# What will be the time Complexity of sorting a 2d array using array.sort() method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

Considering a 2d array with m rows and n columns what is the time complexity of `array.sort()` method in python

Comment: Python uses TimSort, which has average-case O(n log n) complexity. [You an see a breakdown of the complexity of basic python built-in functions here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), including `list.sort()`.

Comment: However, `list.sort()` will only sort the outer dimension of the list.